# TextWrangler and terminal won't run pygame, references wrong python version

Tags: terminal, pygame, python-idle

When I import pygame in IDLE, it works fine. When I try to import pygame through TextWrangler, I get:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper

I believe this is because in IDLE I am running python 3. Is there a way to tell terminal to run Python 3 that I can include in my code in TextWrangler?

I'm a total newb, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Include this at the top of your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```